# What's wrong with my Datatable with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, datatable

I would like to display the first line in the custom list as an image below to `textbox` and `gridview`. However, the `textbox` got the last value, while the `gridview` got the first one.

**Summary: The frist two-textbox must be `ID: 1` & `Name: Huydq`**

[image: Data]

[image: Got]

**C#:**

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public void BindData()
    {
        using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
        {
            using (SPWeb spweb = spsite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
            {
                SPList splist = spweb.Lists["TestWebPart"];
                SPListItemCollection splistitemcollect = splist.Items;
                dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("OverAge", typeof(bool));
                foreach (SPListItem result in splistitemcollect)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    //dr["Title"] = result["Title"];
                    //dr["Name"] = result["Name"];
                    tbID.Text = Convert.ToString(result["Title"]);
                    tbName.Text = Convert.ToString(result["Name"]);
                    dr["Address"] = result["Address"];
                    dr["Email"] = result["Email"];
                    dr["OverAge"] = result["OverAge"];
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            gridView.DataSource = dt;
            gridView.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check the below complete code to bind SharePoint list items to a DataTable/ Gridview. In this post, we are using the list named "Employee" with 5 column: Title, Birthday, Male, Position, Salary. At first, we need to create an empty DataTable with its column

```
protected DataTable dataTableInitiate()
      {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            col.AutoIncrement = true;
            col.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            col.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Birthday", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Male", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(string));                     
            return dt;
      }
```

For binding the item from the SharePoint list to the DataTable that we have just created:

```
protected DataTable bindToDataTable(SPListItemCollection itemCol)
      {
            DataTable dt = dataTableInitiate();
            if (itemCol.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["ID"] = int.Parse(item["ID"].ToString());
                    dr["Title"] = item["Title"] != null ? item["Title"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                    dr["Birthday"] = item["Birthday"] != null ? item["Birthday"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                    dr["Male"] = item["Male"].ToString() == "True" ? "Yes" : "No";
                    dr["Position"] = item["Position"] != null ? item["Position"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                    dr["Salary"] = item["Salary"] != null ? item["Salary"].ToString() : string.Empty;                    
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            return dt;
       }
```

http://deepaksemwalsp.blogspot.com/2012/08/binding-data-from-sharepoint-list-to.html